# codeigniter multiple file upload at once using a single input field

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter, file-upload

I am having a problem in uploading multiple files at once using a single input field,

My HTML form looks like this

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

In my controller I am checking like this

```
echo "<pre>; print_r($_FILES); die;
```

And when I select 2 pdf files, I am getting the output like this

```
Array
(
[files] => Array
    (
        [name] => Array
            (
                [0] => myfile.pdf
            )

        [type] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
            )

        [tmp_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
            )

        [error] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
            )

        [size] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

    )

 )
```

I should be getting 2 array in the output right? So, what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

try the following code in your controller:

```php
echo "<pre>"; 
$_FILES['files']; // change over here
die();
```

Comment: What is this meant to do?

Comment: print the file list stored in the `files`

Comment: I tried this but still displaying the latest selected file and not displaying all the files

Comment: So should there be a `print_r()` or `echo` on the second line?

Comment: Yes I add a print_r() to this

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
print_r($_FILES['files']);
```

If that didn't work, following should work

```
print_r($_FILES['files[]']);
```

Also take a look at [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads)

> Error value 1 : **UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE**
>   The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini. (- [source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php))

You can set those within your code by

```
ini_set('max_file_uploads',1000);
ini_set('post_max_size','5000M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','5000M');
```

Comment: My max_file_uploads is 20
and my post_max_size is 1000M

Comment: print_r($_FILES['files[]']); this is not working too

Comment: What about `upload_max_filesize` ? This must be the problem according to the error value.

Comment: upload_max_filesize = 1000M

Comment: Are you running the code in a local server ? What is the total file sizes ?

Comment: Yes I am running in my local, I am trying to upload 2 files